# Error ITMS-90680:The binary you uploaded was invalid when submitting .ipa file to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, itunes-store

I am trying to upload my .ipa file to App Store but the iTunes connect is rejecting me with the following error :

> Error ITMS-90680:The binary you uploaded was invalid.

I have tried to implement some of the solutions like changing/renewing the developer's certificate and removing third party applications, but none of them seem to be working for me. I will really appreciate if anyone can help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the Application Loader. It will give you a more detailed timeline of the upload so you can narrow down what is going wrong.

Comment: How are you trying to upload it? Archive and Upload, or Application Loader?

Comment: @dfd I am archiving the project and then uploadingng

Comment: @DanielStorm Thank you, I will try doing it with application loader and let you know.